# Php code to see if two lines are parallel

Tags: php, math

I want to write a PHP code to see if two lines are parallel.

We have

```
The four points are P(x1, y1), Q(x2, y2), R(x3, y3), S(x4, y4)



<?php
 fscanf(STDIN, '%d', $n); 
for ($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++) {
    fscanf(STDIN, '%f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f', $x1, $y1, $x2, $y2, $x3, $y3, $x4, $y4);
    $pq = INF;
    if ($x2 - $x1 !== 0.0) {
        $pq = ($y1 - $y2) / ($x1 - $y1);
    }
    $rs = INF;
    if ($x4 - $x3 !== 0.0) {
        $rs = ($x4 - $x3) / ($x3 - $y4);
    } 
    echo $pq === $rs ? 'PQ and RS are parallel.' : 'PQ and RS are not parallel.';
    echo PHP_EOL;
}
?>
```

But it's not working correct even if given two parallel lines

Comment: Floats are imprecise, so you can't simply compare them using equivalence because they will virtually never be equal unless they were calculated from exactly the same base vaules. Use something like: `abs( $float1 - $float2 ) < $some_precision;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Slope is equal to `m = (y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1)`

I made some changes in your formula so it's working I think.

```
<?php
 fscanf(STDIN, '%d', $n); 
for ($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++) {
    fscanf(STDIN, '%f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f', $x1, $y1, $x2, $y2, $x3, $y3, $x4, $y4);
    $pq = INF;
    if ($x2 - $x1 !== 0.0) {
        $pq = ($y2 - $y1) / ($x2 - $x1);
    }
    $rs = INF;
    if ($x4 - $x3 !== 0.0) {
        $rs = ($y4 - $y3) / ($x4 - $x3);
    } 
    echo $pq === $rs ? 'PQ and RS are parallel.' : 'PQ and RS are not parallel.';
    echo PHP_EOL;
}
?>
```

it's just a math problem

Comment: The math is fixed, but the fact remains that you cannot reliably compare two floating point numbers using `==` or `===`.

Comment: Thanks.so what is your suggestion ? What should I do? Now app works very good